# Unable to format Date cell in exported excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using `Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();`for exporting an excel sheet, which contains a column which is a **DATE**. Even after setting the style as **DATE**, the column is shown as **GENERAL** in the Excel sheet.

Here is my piece of code for cell creation

```
Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
int rowValue = 1; CellStyle cellStyleOfHeaderRow = wb.createCellStyle(); CellStyle style = wb.createCellStyle(); 
Font fontOfCell = initializeCellFont(wb, cellStyleOfHeaderRow); initializeCellBorders(cellStyleOfHeaderRow); initializeCellFillOptions(cellStyleOfHeaderRow); 
initializeCellBorders(style); CreationHelper createHelper = wb.getCreationHelper(); 
    short dateFormat = createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss"); 
    style.setDataFormat(dateFormat);
```

After opening the exported excel, when I try to change the format of the date column from **GENERAL** to **DATE**, I am unable to do so.

[image]

Could you suggest some piece of code or any solution to this?

Comment: Show us the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Could you show us your piece of code first? I mean the one that applies the cell values and styles...

Comment: Well, please [edit] the code into your question instead of posting it as a comment. What I can see in your comment is a very strange looking date-time pattern: `yyyy-MM-dd-hh.mm.ss`. The `h` for hours should be capitalized and I wouldn't put a hyphon between the day and the hours. Maybe, you are preventing Excel from interpreting this as a valid date time... It is not a date only, because it holds information about the time of day, too.

Comment: The code of the `style` looks good,
can you please also clarify how do you apply the value and style to the date cells ?

Answer (score 3):

I suspect your data `2016-01-28 12:06:00.0`, ... are Strings rather than Dates. If you set strings in a `Excel` cell, then the cell cannot be a date cell. The cell value must be a numeric value to let the cell be a date cell. So you needs converting that `String`s to `Date`s before setting the cell value. Then set that `Date` as the cell value.

Using current `apache poi 4.1.2` this can be done using `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` and `java.time.LocalDateTime` since there is [Cell.setCellValue(java.time.LocalDateTime value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-java.time.LocalDateTime-) now.

Up to `apache poi 3.17` it can be done using `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date`. [Cell.setCellValue(java.util.Date value)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue-java.util.Date-) is the setCellValue method used then.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

class CreateExcelDateCells {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
       FileOutputStream fileout = new FileOutputStream("Excel.xlsx") ) {

   String[][] data = new String[][] {
    new String[] {"Date"},
    new String[] {"2016-01-28 12:06:00.0"},
    new String[] {"2016-01-27 08:29:00.0"},
    new String[] {"2016-01-18 21:37:00.0"}
   };

   DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", Locale.US);
   //SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", Locale.US); // up to apache poi 3.17

   CellStyle dateCellStyle = workbook.createCellStyle();
   dateCellStyle.setDataFormat(workbook.createDataFormat().getFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(); 

   for (int r = 0; r < data.length; r++) {
    Row row = sheet.createRow(r);
    Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
    if (r == 0) {
     cell.setCellValue(data[r][0]); // String cell value
    } else {
     cell.setCellValue(LocalDateTime.parse(data[r][0], dateTimeFormatter)); // Date cell value
     //cell.setCellValue(simpleDateFormatter.parse(data[r][0])); // Date cell value up to apache poi 3.17
     cell.setCellStyle(dateCellStyle);
    }
   }

   sheet.autoSizeColumn(0);

   workbook.write(fileout);
  }

 }
}
```

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S", Locale.US);`
I tried using this and checked if my Time.equals(simpleDateFormatter), but it does not work.

Comment: @champ.exe: I have given a complete working example in my answer. This is tested and works. Not clear what "I tried using this and checked if my Time.equals(simpleDateFormatter), but it does not work." means. What exactly have you tried? What is `Time` in your case? And how shall `Time.equals(simpleDateFormatter)` be used?

Comment: I have a list of other columns to add so I have taken an Object[] which has Date, Time, etc, so here i am trying to check if the Time is of the specific format specified, I am trying to convert it to double so it can be modified in the Excel.
If it is not a dateTimeFormat, for eg Name, it can be added as a String

Comment: @champ.exe: "i am trying to check if the Time is of the specific format specified": A `Time` does not have any format unless one is formatting it. So always not clear where your problem is. But this is nothing what can discussed in comments here.

Comment: Time is of the same format as mentioned in the image